# SQL Server float datatype

Tags: sql-server, floating-point

The documentation for [SQL Server Float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) says

> Approximate-number data types for use
>   with floating point numeric data.
>   Floating point data is approximate;
>   therefore, not all values in the data
>   type range can be represented exactly.

Which is what I expected it to say. If that is the case though why does the following return 'Yes' in SQL Server (unexpected)

```
DECLARE @D float
DECLARE @E float

set @D = 0.1
set @E = 0.5

IF ((@D + @D + @D + @D +@D) = @E)
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'YES'
 END 
ELSE
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'NO'
 END
```

but the equivalent C++ program returns "No" (expected as 0.1 can't be represented exactly but 0.5 can)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
float d = 0.1F;
float e = 0.5F;

if((d+d+d+d+d) == e)
 {
 cout << "Yes";
 }
else
 {
 cout << "No";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be caused by different rounding strategies, the order in which operands are applied, the way intermediate results are stored and much more. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for details. If you are not absolutely sure you know what you are doing, you should avoid equality comparisons in floating point number computations.

Comment: +1 I think your first point on rounding strategies may well have been bang on the money. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx "The IEEE 754 specification provides four rounding modes: round to nearest, round up, round down, and round to zero. Microsoft SQL Server uses round up.".

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a new answer, I would like to add some quotes from [technet.microsoft.com - Using decimal, float, and real Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Avoid using float or real columns in WHERE clause search conditions, especially the = and <> operators. It is best to limit float and real columns to > or < comparisons.

Also, as you know, the intention is described below:

> The float and real data types are known as approximate data types. The behavior of float and real follows the IEEE 754 specification on approximate numeric data types.
>
> The IEEE 754 specification provides four rounding modes: round to nearest, round up, round down, and round to zero. Microsoft SQL Server uses round up.

About Decimal and Numeric

> Use the decimal data type to store numbers with decimals when the data values must be stored exactly as specified.
> In Transact-SQL, numeric is functionally equivalent to the decimal data type.